# iMac keeps booting from internal HDD after update

Tags: imac, startup, ssd

I have an iMac Late 2013 with an SSD connected externally where I have macOS installed and it was set as the default boot drive. I've been booting from the SSD for about 3 years without a problem.

Last night I installed an update for Catalina and after it was installed it boot from the internal HDD. Now any time I turn on my iMac it boots by default from the HDD instead of the SSD.

If I hold the option key before booting I can choose to boot from the SSD. In `System Preferences -> Startup disk` I can see that the SSD is selected, and everything works fine as usual. But if I turn off and on the iMac it boots again from the HDD.

<strike>When it boots from the HDD, if I go to `System Preferences -> Startup disk` I can only see the HDD, the SSD doesn't appear as an option and neither appears on finder.</strike>

Comment: What macOS is on the internal drive? I', guessing it is too old to be able to recognise APFS.

Comment: @Tetsujin good point. I updated to Catalina on the HDD and now I can see the SSD as an option. Unfortunately the problem still persist even if both installs have selected the SSD as the startup disk.

Comment: All I can think is to try persuading it again. Set it from the control panel to boot to the internal, reboot & then re-set to the external. See if that jogs its elbow a bit.